# Hue - Docker produces errors that it can't connect

Tags: docker, hadoop, hive, hue

I'm currently trying to use `Hue` to connect to `Hive` to query data in my `hadoop` cluster.
I have `Hive` and `Hadoop` set up.
Because I'm having a hard time building the Hue package, I decided to go with the Docker Image.
When I run the docker image, I get the following results.

```
Could not connect to any of [('127.0.0.1', 10000), ('127.0.0.1', 10000)] (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException("Could not connect to any of [('127.0.0.1', 10000), ('127.0.0.1', 10000)]",)
```

I do have Hive running on port 10000, so I don't know why there's an error. Also how do I edit the .ini file in a docker image?

Answer (score 2):

`127.0.0.1` is the Docker Hue image, you would mean to `docker inpect` your Docker Hive and put the custom IP of this running container in the hue.ini and mount it:

e.g.

https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/tools/docker/hue
https://docs.gethue.com/administrator/configuration/connectors/#apache-hive

Example: https://gethue.com/blog/quickstart-sql-editor-for-apache-impala/ (note: would need to mount the local ini still)

Comment: I think the question is misunderstood. I am able to access the Docker Image via the browser, however in the user interface I see the following error:Could not connect to any of [('127.0.0.1', 10000), ('127.0.0.1', 10000)] (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException("Could not connect to any of [('127.0.0.1', 10000), ('127.0.0.1', 10000)]",

Comment: cf. above if Hive hostname is not 127.0.0.1 you need to change it to the proper hostname. There is also a recent blog post about this https://gethue.com/quickstart-hue-in-docker/

Comment: @vinh Tran Hi, do you solve the problem? I have the same issue....